# Stuck on Java Recursion Puzzle

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to java and I have recently decided to learn recursion. There is this puzzle that I must solve using a recursive method. 
The puzzle is a list on integers where you start at the first element and the goal is to reach the last element, that is always zero. Now you have to move right or left in the list and number of times you can do so is determined by the element you are currently on. You cannot move outside the list either, and cannot use subList. My method is suppose to see if the given puzzle is solvable. Current code has StackoverFlow and I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: if you are getting a stackoverflow, you are exceeding the depth you can recurse or you don't actually have an exit state, or both.

Comment: When you use the `.size()` method, try `.size() -1`

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that your recursive function is never hitting return false somewhere down the line and its just recurrsing until you run out of stack space.  I'd start looking there.

Comment: Andrew, will it return false with the BeenOn.contains(index) at any point?

Comment: the BeenOn list will be empty every time you enter this method. This needs to be passed into each method call so that you can keep the elements added each iteration.

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect either way. Consider `5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0` and starting at `index = 1`. It will return false because when you get to the `2`, you jump back to a field you've been on. If you moved to the left in the beginning rather than right, it would be solvable, though.

Comment: My mistake, the starting index is always `0`. In this case an example where this algorithm fails is `5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0`.

Comment: It was rebecca that helped me none of the answers below though

Comment: Code example showing problem is essential part of question, so don't remove it and don't change it into one which is your solution. How others should tell in the future which answer was correct if they won't see original problem? If you want to show how you corrected your code then post it as answer (you will be able to do it probably after some time limit) but absolutely do not include it in question. Questions are suppose to describe problems, not show how you solved it.

Comment: Can I know why do you want to remove code from your question? I'm starting to suspect that for some reasons you don't want to make it public. If so then maybe just rename some variables, methods in your code you are going to use to not resemble this one.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see this, I will do what you just said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with the algorithm.

The last thing the method 'isSolveable' does is returns forward or backwards solveability. Instead of returning, try the forward solveability first, then if that fails, try the backwards solveability.

The 'BeenOn' list isn't passed to each isSolveable() method invocation so its always empty each time the method is called. You can just create one on first call and pass it along each time you call the method.

Also you arn't checking if its out of bounds quite right. list.size() will always be 1 greater than the actual index of the last position in the list, since lists start at 0, not 1. So your last index would be `board.size() - 1`

```
public static boolean isSolvable(int index, List<Integer> board, List<Integer> visitedIndices) {
    int lastIndex = board.size() - 1;
    if (index == lastIndex) {
        // Last index. solved
        return true;
    }

    if (index > lastIndex || index < 0 || visitedIndices.contains(index)) {
        // Outside list or previously vistied, failed to solve
        return false;
    }

    visitedIndices.add(index);
    int nextIndexForward = index + board.get(index);
    int nextIndexBackward = index - board.get(index);

    return isSolvable(nextIndexForward, board, visitedIndices)
           || isSolvable(nextIndexBackward, board, visitedIndices);
}
```

Comment: Could be made simpler by simply doing `return isSolvable(nextIndexForward, …) || isSolvable(nextIndexBackward, …)`, but other than that this should be correct.

Comment: Just as a note, it would be cleaner to not pass these arguments but rather have a class for this purpose, but this is a bit closer to what the OP had.

Answer (score 2):

DangerDan's answer contains all the information. As an alternative I want to show a solution that is class-based rather than passing around arguments. This way it's a bit cleaner:

```
public class Puzzle {

    private final List<Integer> board;
    private final List<Integer> visitedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Puzzle(List<Integer> board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public boolean isSolvable() {
        return isSolvableAtIndex(0);
    }

    private boolean isSolvableAtIndex(int index) {
        int lastIndex = board.size() - 1;
        if(index == lastIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        if(index < 0 || index > lastIndex || visitedIndices.contains(index)) {
            return false;
        }

        visitedIndices.add(index);

        int step = board.get(index);
        return isSolvableAtIndex(index + step) || isSolvableAtIndex(index - step);
    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0));
System.out.println("Puzzle is solvable: " + puzzle.isSolvable() ? "yes" : "no"); // "Puzzle is solvable: yes"
```